# iOS: Use a boolean in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, boolean, nsuserdefaults, modalviewcontroller

When the `rootViewController` of my application is loaded, I want to be able to check whether or not the users login credentials have been saved to `NSUserDefaults`.

Basically, when the user loads the application and he/she doesn't have her login credentials saved, a `modalAlertView` will be pushed and the user will be able to save their credentials appropriately. This saves those `UITextField` strings to a respective `NSUserDefault` object. However, is it possible, that when this saving is done, I can create an `NSUserDefault` object which is a boolean and change the value to a yes?

Meaning that the boolean is already set to no, and when the user saves their login credentials, it also changes the boolean to a yes?

Answer (score 269, accepted):

You can set your boolean by using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"logged_in"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and read it by using this code:

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"logged_in"]) {
    [self displayLogin];
} else {
    [self displayMainScreen];
}
```

Comment: @Henril P .Can it display the same user which was login previously

Answer (score 11):

There is a method in `NSUserDefaults` called `registerDefaults:`. You  use this method to set your application's "default defaults." Basically, you create an `NSDictionary` containing your default keys and values (in your case a NO for a "saved credentials" key), and you register it using `registerDefaults:`. This if often done in app delegate's `+ (void)initialize` method to ensure that your defaults are registered before they are needed. These values only get used if your app hasn't replaced them. In other words, they won't be used unless the key you're looking for isn't in the Application Domain, i.e., the user defaults read from the user's .plist file.

On the other hand, you could just check for login credentials and pop up an alert if they're missing. This eliminates the need to keep your boolean value synchronized with the login credentials. If you later provide a "delete login credentials" capability, you won't have to remember to set the boolean back to NO. If your login credentials are saved in user's defaults, you'd do this:

```
NSString *userID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userID"];
NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password"];
if (userID != nil && password != nil) {
    // Code to log user in
} else {
    // Code to pop up an alert
}
```

Comment: how would I go about writing a method that checks the login credentials and just pops up the alert if they're not saved?

Comment: You shouldn't even think about storing passwords in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 7):

This solution, suggested by Henrik P. Hessel:

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"logged_in"]) {
[self displayLogin];
} else {
[self displayMainScreen];
}
```

would work in your case, but bear in mind that you shouldn't check with this code if some key is set at all, because if it actually is set and set to "NO", you would still get a result as if was not set at all. Instead I would use

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"logged_in"] == nil) {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to first set it to `NO`, instead you may check if a key has been set at all. If not, and if your app determines the credentials are complete, just create it and set it to `YES`.

Check [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759761/nsuserdefaults-problem/3759905#3759905) to see how I usually do this.

Answer (score 0):

**in Swift 3**

```
let Defaults = UserDefaults.standard()()
let exists = Defaults.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn")

if !exists {
   displayLoginScreen()            
} else {
   print("value exists..do something")
   displayMainScreen()       
}
```

alternatively we can use `object(forKey:)` then cast it to bool

```
if let exists = Defaults.object(forKey: "isLoggedIn"), let isLoggedIn = exists.boolValue where isLoggedIn == true {
  displayMainScreen()
} else {
  displayLoginScreen() 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 2.3**

To store values

```
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "logged_in")
```

For fetching values

```
  if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("logged_in") == true {
      dashboardScreen()
  }else {
      loginScreen()
  }
```

**Swift 3.0**

To store values

```
  UserDefaults.standard().setBool(true, forKey: "logged_in")
```

to retrieve values

```
  UserDefaults.standard().bool(forKey: "logged_in"){
      dashboardScreen()
  }else {
      loginScreen()
  }
```