# Store ON/OFF switch in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I have an app where I use NSUserDefaults to determine if it is the first time someone opens the app.  If it is the first time, the app displays a tutorial page.

Now, I would like to change this so that if the user moves an ON/OFF switch to "ON", they will not see the tutorial when they start up the app.  How do I store the user's selection of an ON/OFF switch in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841166/how-to-use-a-boolean-in-nsuserdefaults

Comment: add some code where you are setting the value for NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did something like this with the following code:

Store it:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"the_key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //Thanks Henri Normak
```

Retrieve it:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"the_key"]
```

Comment: Just don't forget to call [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Comment: ^ Good catch. I totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in an NSNumber numberWithBool:.

```
[defaults setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:mySwitch.on] forKey:@"mySwitchValue"];

// and get it out
BOOL savedSwitch = [[defaults valueForKey:@"mySwitchValue"] boolValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two bool keys to be saved in NSUserDefaults to get the what you want. e.g. **firstTime** is used check first time app launch, **showTutorial** is used to check/save the switch change

You can set your boolean by using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstTime"];
```

and read it by using this code:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"showTutorial"] || [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstTime"]) {
    [self displayTutorial];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"firstTime"];
} 
else {
    [self displayMainScreen];
}
```

Link the UISwitch on View from InterfaceBuilder to this action on valuechanged

```
-(IBAction)userSetOnOff:(id)sender
 {
      UISwitch *switchValue = sender;
      if (switchValue.on){
           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"showTutorial"];
      }
      else{
           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"showTutorial"];
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In one of my apps I check to see if NSUserDefaults has been used and if not set the one standard User Default variable.

-(id) init

{

```
standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *testInitState = [standardUserDefaults stringForKey:kInstallInit];
if (testInitState == nil)
{

    #if(kStateModelDebug)
    NSLog(@" State Model: First time initialized");
    #endif
    [self.standardUserDefaults setObject:@"true"  forKey:kInstallInit];
    [self.standardUserDefaults synchronize];

    // Start the tutorials, init DB, etc


}
else 
{
    #if(kStateModelDebug)
    NSLog(@" State Model has ALREADY been initialized");
    #endif

    // Read other state variables and/or init the startup processes

}
return self;
```

}

So far , up to ios 5.0 and the new 6.0, this has been a solution.  Looking for comments on this solution.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to simply persist a string with the switch status. If the user prefers the on position you'd store the string `@"on"`. Else store the string `@"off"`.

```
- (void) toggleUserPreference:(BOOL) preferOn {
    NSString *newPreference = preferOn ? @"on" : @"off";
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:newPreference
                                             forKey:ONOFF_PREFERENCE_KEY];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Or just use `- setBool:forKey:` to store the and `- boolForKey:` to get the result.

Comment: The most straightforward way is to use [boolForKey:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/boolForKey:)