# How can I save the state of a button to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, button, nsuserdefaults

I need help trying to do a crude type of confirmation where you need to type: I got it! into a `NSTextField` then press `button1` so that once they do press `button1` I make my `button2` enabled using

```
 -(IBAction)check:(id)sender{
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithValue:@"I Got It!"];
    if(field.stringValue isEqualToString:string){
      [field setHidden:YES];
      [button1 setHidden:YES];
      [button2 setEnabled:YES]
    }
  }
```

This is only a one-time confirmation so I'm wondering how I can save the state of the button so that next time they launch the app they don't have to do the confirmation again. The textfield and `button1` will be hidden and so that `button2` will always be enabled, I want to use the `NSUserDefaults` because I think that would be the easiest for me to understand.

Comment: use an NSNumber @0 or @1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a boolean in NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841166/how-to-use-a-boolean-in-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as below

> if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
>   boolForKey:@"ishidden"] != YES){
>
> // First launch
>
> } else { //not first launch }

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at  [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html). You can use `- (void)setBool:(BOOL)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName`