# Mute UILocalNotifications sending for a certain time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

My app notifies (using `UILocalNotification`) the user every time he approaches one of the stores of my client, even in the background.

I have a mute button that when the user clicks on, an actionSheet pops and asks the him for how long he would like to mute the app (5h, 24h, 1 week or 1 month).

When the user chooses one of the options, I want the app to stop sending notifications until this time will pass.

What is the best way to do this?

I'll really appreciate a code example.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  Since your app has to generate the notifications, why not calculate the expiration of the mute period and store it.  Before generating a new notification, check the current date against the stored date.

Comment: @Avi can you give me a code example for this? Maybe I'll understand it more

Comment: Which part is hard?  storing the date for future comparison?  Generating the date? Comparing the date?  You haven't even given us any code to look at.

Comment: @Avi Thanks for the answer I understood what you mean now. But I have also an option in the actionSheet that the notifications won't be sent until the user unmute manually from the app. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//fire local notification 

    NSDate * storedDate // Store your date when setting the mute 
    int tillHoursForMute // hours for mute

    muteDate  = <storedDate+tillHoursForMute> //concatenate the hours into date
   if ([muteDate compare:firingDate] == NSOrderedDescending && [muteDate compare:firingDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    //fire Notification        

   } else {
      //Mute time

  }
```

Note : Just written the steps, Change it as per language stands.

Comment: This is really horrible pseudocode, because you shouldn't compare dates that way.

Comment: let him handle with respective coding

Comment: Store that option as a boolean value (`NSUserDefaults` is a good place).  Don't create the notification if that value is set, *or* if there is an expiration date that hasn't passed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841166/how-to-use-a-boolean-in-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Thanks you very much!