# iOS - NSUserdefaults always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsuserdefaults

I'm having trouble with the user defaults, in the *settings.bundle - root.plist* I did the following entry:

[image]

When checking the value with:

```
BOOL showTutorial = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SettingsShowTutorialOnLaunch"] boolValue];
```

I always getting a nil (Boolean NO) ... I've checked the identifier several times (no space at the end). It simply looks like I have no access to the UserDefaults - do I need to include a header or something to get access?

///// CORRECT ANSWER /////

I can't post an answer to my question as it was marked as duplicate already. The solution in my case was adding a registerDefaults:

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YES" forKey:@"SettingsShowTutorialOnLaunch"]];
```

A very good tutorial is this one here: http://www.accella.net/knowledgebase/nsuserdefaults-some-pretty-good-practices/

Comment: Nothing from the settings bundle will appear in user defaults until the user runs the Settings app, goes to the page for your app, and changes a setting value.

Comment: A better answer is this one: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759761/nsuserdefaults-problem/3759905)