# How to access the Device token from didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken to my ViewDidLoad method

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I know this is very basic but I need to pull my device token and Store it in a String and put(display) it on a label on my ViewDidLoad method. What might be the posible solution? Im new on iOS development. Should I use Global variable? or any Posible Solution?

This is my code.

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];

NSLog(@"%@", str);

//get the string and display it on the ViewDidLoad method.

}
```

Please help me. How to use global variable to access that string?

on my ViewController.m class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSString *getToken = @"Token from AppDelegate";

}
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the token into user defaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:str forKey:@"DEVICE_TOKEN"];
```

And then in your viewDidLoad:

```
NSString *getToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"DEVICE_TOKEN"];
```

But there are other approaches: global variable, persistence layer, `NSNotification`, and so on.

EDIT:

[Here you have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2078651/1034126) info about how to register the standard user defaults.

EDIT2:

In order to obtain the token string, I do the following

```
NSString *deviceTokenString = [deviceToken description];
deviceTokenString = [deviceTokenString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
deviceTokenString = [deviceTokenString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Then, in `deviceTokenString` you end having the full value without whitespaces or any other character. Just ready to trigger push notifications.

Comment: You should really be doing the conversion from data to a hex string manually, instead of relying on the implementation of -[NSData description].

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a category on UIApplication (or a UIApplication subclass) for storing the current push token.

```
@interface MyApplication : UIApplication

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSData *pushToken;

@end
```

As @amb mentioned, there are a lot of different ways to go about it.